# presentViewController not working in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

In this code the alert action is shown every time the app become active:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];


}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please make your choice"
                                                                         message:@"Would you like a cup of coffee?"
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                      NSLog(@"You tapped YES");
                                                  }];

    UIAlertAction *maybeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"MAYBE"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                        NSLog(@"You tapped MAYBE");
                                                    }];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:yesAction];
    [alertController addAction:maybeAction];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also, everything works as expected if I move the code block of the UIAlertController in **viewDidAppear** method.

But if I move the UIAlertController in **viewDidLoad** :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIAlertController *alertController [...]
    [...]
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

it doesn't works. The alert is not shown.

Comment: Do you have a question? So far you have just made some statements.

Comment: The question is: why the alert is not shown if invoked in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Do you see any message in the console when you try to display the alert from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Ouch! I see this:  `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x13550e280> on <ViewController: 0x13560a470> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidLoad it is not part of the view hierarchy at that time hence it is silently ignored, on viewWillAppear at this time the view hierarchy is already set up hence the reason it works.

Comment: fyi, You have a typo in your response... it's viewDIDAppear, not viewWillAppear..

Comment: It is not work for me ,I have to show two alert 1 by 1 ,But it only display first alert ....I have used alertviewController

Comment: It's `viewDidAppear` that fixed my issue.