# Why is the incorrect ViewController Showing? and how do I display the correct one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am trying to send the user to a registration page if they have not already registered a username etc..  I can't get the registration viewController to load, it only loads the MainViewController.
I've tried every method I can find but nothing works..  My background is Java/Android so this is all very new.  A point in the right direction would be much appreciated..

Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




    BOOL hasRegistered = YES;

    if (!hasRegistered)
    {
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registrationView"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: In your current code, you just initialized the viewController. There is no present, push done.

Comment: I've updated my code, but it still just does nothing, Only shows the first viewcontroller - I get the message "Warning: Attempt to present <registrationViewController: 0x10ff0e830> on <ViewController: 0x10fd11590> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: Have you use navigationController in your project?

Comment: Yes it is definitely there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [presentViewController not working in viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978487/presentviewcontroller-not-working-in-viewdidload)

Comment: @astricmobiles is my answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
registrationViewController *viewController = (registrationViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registrationView"];
```

instead of

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registrationView"];
```

If you show the view controller modally the use this to open

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or if you use `navigationController` then

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```